# How do I fix "ReferenceError: System is not defined" when running script from command line?

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I'm trying to create typescript server side (example code `import mongoose from 'mongoose';`
) and I know I'm supposed to get systemjs initialized before, but I don't know how to in a server side script.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to use module 'system' at server side - you will have to install systemjs package and configure it:

```
import System = require('systemjs');

System.config({
  ...
});

System.import(...);
```

But in my opinion it would be better to target commonjs and run it 'natively' in node.js without any extra dependencies.

As a bonus - you can also run commonjs module in browser using systemjs as loader - it supports loading them out of the box.

[EDIT]

Note that node.js is build with commonjs as module standard. Therefore you can consume 'system' modules using SystemJS but only 'inside' your main program that must be in commonjs format to be able to run in nodejs.

Comment: I "think" I know what you're trying to tell me to do, and I even really appreciate your opinion on the matter of just dumping systemjs on the server side, but I'm having a problem still trying to just "try" using systemjs. Using your code in my .ts file I get "Cannot find name 'require'.

Comment: it looks like you are missing node.js definitions that includes require. Try adding the following line to your typings.json file: `"node": "github:DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/node/node.d.ts"` and run `typings install`

Comment: If I use `import System = require('systemjs')` compilation succeeds... Is there a difference? Either way, I still get `System is not defined` when `node myscript.js`

Comment: You should use import, my bad. I have tried it locally. After installing systemjs package and importing definitions - its works fine and System is defined.

Comment: Ok now I think I understand what you are trying to do. You do can compile some modules in 'system' format but, you cannot load them directly in node.js environment. As node.js use commonjs as standard. So compilling you app.ts targeting 'system' will not run in node.js. But what you can do is to compile your app.ts targeting commonjs, and from within using systemjs package load other modules compiled targeting 'system'. Hope this sorts it  out for you.

Comment: So I see now that is not an issue with TypeScript at all. A matter of curiosity, is it possible to use systemjs in my scenario? Or is this just not possible in nodejs?

Comment: You can use systemjs modules but not 'natively'. Your app must be compiled targeting commonjs, and then from within you can using System.import() load modules in other formats than commonjs.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this by putting `"module" : "commonjs"` in the tsconfig.json. Commonjs is the historic node module system.